# Missing command error; Creating custom cordova plugin for Windows 10 app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to call a C# class to with a custom plugin. I'm using Cordova to create a universal Windows 10 application. here is my C# class called Echo.cs

```
using System;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

public class Echo : BaseCommand
{
    public void echo(string options)
    {
        // all JS callable plugin methods MUST have this signature!
        // public, returning void, 1 argument that is a string

        DispatchCommandResult();
    }
}
```

When device is ready I call

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.

    var win = function (result) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(result);
    };
    var fail = function (result) {
        console.log("Fail");
        console.log(result);
    };

    cordova.exec(win, fail, "Echo", "echo", ["input string"]);
};
```

It however always fails with this error; Missing Command Error. it seems it can't find the class?

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/wp8/plugin.html

Is no help. Anything I might have missed? I've tried putting the .cs file in a different project (belonging to the same solution), in the plugin folder, in the root folder etc.

Comment: DId you define a empty constructor within the actual class definition Echo? You can also examine my [class](https://github.com/blauharley/Cordova-Reminder/blob/master/src/wp8/Reminder.cs)

Comment: Did you resolved? Same error here

Comment: @AndréVicente I didn't finish my project, however I found a cordova plugin that successfully calls a C# file from javascript. You can use this as an example
https://github.com/blauharley/Cordova-Reminder